# Is there a product formula for the Bernouilli numbers?

Tags: infinite-product, bernoulli-numbers

There are many well-known formulas available for the Bernouilli numbers, many of these can be found on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). However, these are all in the form of infinite sums. I have not found any of the form

$$
\prod_n R(n),
$$

where $R(n)$ is a rational function. Does such a representation exist?

Comment: I doubt it **very** much. If it existed, then it would have been found by now.